# 3D FEM - How to use element markers for boundary integration

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I am having trouble integrating over some curved boundaries and was thinking about using the element markers of the boundary mesh for integration rather than conditionals.

**Is it possible to use boundary element markers for `NIntegrate`?** I could only find documentation on element markers being used for boundary conditions with `NDSolve`.

I am hoping to get rid of inaccuracies regarding the tolerance specified with conditional integration as well as making it faster, as I hope it won't have to check the condition on all of the boundary elements, but rather only on the subset of boundary elements regarding the specific region marker.

I am using Mathematica 12.1

Find some example code below, some integration over a cuboid:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*Mesh generation*)
xmax = 1;
ymax = 1;
zmax = 1;

cubi = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {xmax, ymax, zmax}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[cubi]

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh]

(*Mesh and marker visualization*)
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;

surfaces = 
  AssociationThread[groups, 
   bmesh["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == #, 
       "MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm[colors[[#]]]]] & /@ groups];

Manipulate[
 Show[{bmesh["Edgeframe"], choices /. surfaces}], {{choices, groups}, 
  groups, CheckboxBar}, ControlPlacement -> Top]

bmesh["Wireframe"[
  ElementMarker == 
   1]] (*Here I can access the boundary element subset defined by the \
element marker*)
```

[image: Element Marker stuff]

Here is the integration part:

```
(*Conditional integration*)
tolerance = 1*10^-6;
boundaryFront [x_, y_, z_] := Abs[x] <= tolerance;
boundaryFrontPart[x_, y_, z_][ymin_,ymax_] := (Abs[x] <= tolerance && ymin <= y <= ymax);

areaTest1 = 
 NIntegrate[
  Piecewise[{{1, boundaryFront[x, y, z]}, {0, True}}], {x, y, 
    z} \[Element] 
   mesh] (*does not work, integrating over mesh not boundary mesh*)

areaTest2 = 
 NIntegrate[
  Piecewise[{{1, boundaryFront[x, y, z]}, {0, True}}], {x, y, 
    z} \[Element] bmesh](*works*)

areaTest3 = NIntegrate[
  Piecewise[{{1, 
     boundaryFrontPart[x, y, z][0.25 ymax, 0.75 ymax]}, {0, 
     True}}], {x, y, z} \[Element] bmesh(*works, 
  integrating only some y-coords*)
  ]

(*Test integrating parts*)
numPieces = 10;
deltaY = ymax/numPieces;
pieces = Table[
  NIntegrate[
   Piecewise[{{1, 
      boundaryFrontPart[x, y, z][num*deltaY, (num + 1)*deltaY]}, {0, 
      True}}], {x, y, z} \[Element] bmesh]
  , {num, 0, numPieces - 1}]
areaTest4 = Plus @@ pieces

areaTest5 = NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] bmesh] (*Integrating area of whole bmesh*)
```

What I would like to do:

```
   bmeshPart = some function of bmesh and element marker
   
   areaTest6=Nintegrate[1,{x,y,z}\[Element]bmeshPart]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does something like this work for you:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
FEMNBoundaryIntegrate[1, {x, y, z}, mesh, 
 ElementMarker == 1 || ElementMarker == 3]
2.`
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great.